# Removing extra comma from a column while exporting the data into csv file using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, csv, export-to-csv, azure-data-factory

I am having data in my sql table as shown below screenshot, which is having an extra comma in values column after the values. It is actually list of values which is having more values.
[image]

I have to import this data into a pipe delimited csv file. And it is shown as below screenshot.
[image]

How will I remove the additional comma from that column while importing the data into a csv file with pipe delimiter.

I am performing the import using an azure data factory pipeline. Is there any way to avoid the extra comma from imported file or while importing?

Is there any way to make this changes at the time of importing the file to an ADLS location through ADF? Any changes that has to be make in ADF?

Comment: You can either remove it while reading the source (IE a SQL Query/stored procedure) or use a Data Flow to trim the comma in flight. The SQL approach would probably be faster and less expensive.

Answer (score 0):

As Joel commented, you can just modify your query to do that while extracting. It might look like this:

```
select ID, timestamp, replace([values], ',', '') as values from [YourTable]
```

Hope this helped!